# Add reasonable-looking table to matplotlib axes (HTML?)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I would like to make a 2-part graphic.  On the left, I want to have a visualization (that I already know how to make).  On the right, I want to place a table that includes more numerical data about the same subject covered by the graph.  Say I set things up with `axes[0]` for the visualization and `axes[1]` as the place where I want the table.

I'm using Pandas, and I have all the info I'd like for my table in a nice neat `DataFrame`.  (For now, let's assume that `DataFrame` has a regular `Index` on both the rows and the columns, not a `MultiIndex`, but I'm curious how answers would change if we dropped that assumption.)  Let's call that `tabledf`.

What's the easiest way to take `tabledf` and draw it on `axes[1]`?  In particular, it'd be great if it could look just like the HTML representation of `tabledf`.  Is there a way to draw an HTML table onto a matplotlib set of axes?

I can certainly do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

tabledf = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(5,3),
                       index=list('abcde'),
                       columns=list('xyz'))



fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 5))
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
axes[0].plot(x, np.sin(x))
axes[1].axis('off')
axes[1].table(cellText=tabledf.values, loc='center')
```

which gets me:
[image]

I have 2 problems with this.  1) It's hideous.  2) If I wanted to graft the row labels and column labels onto this strucutre I'd have to do a lot of array glueing.  I thought there had to be a better way.

---

Edit: Ideally, the table portion on the right would look just like the default Pandas HTML representation of `tabledf`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no easy way to do it with HTML and `matplotlib`. However, you should be able to do it using LaTeX.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
mpl.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"].append(r'\usepackage{tabularx}')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([0,1], [1,0])

ax.text(.5, .5, r'''\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | } \hline & x & y & z \\\hline a & 1.62 & -0.61 & -0.528 \\\hline \end{tabular}''')
```

creates:

[image]

Of course, you may and should generate the table from your data by using some simple code. The LaTeX tables are quite flexible once you grasp the way they are built.

To make the solution above work you need to have a well-configured LaTeX distro in your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm moderately familiar with generating tables in LaTeX.  My experience is that it's a bit of a pain.  It looks like `pandas.DataFrame` has a `to_latex` method.  Seems like that's the next place I should look.

Comment: @8one6: If you do not like `tabular`, you may use any LaTeX package. The output of `to_latex` is IIRC for the `booktab` package. However, beware that the `matplotlib` LaTeX system does not necessarily like line breaks, so you may need to replace `\n` by spaces in the string given by `to_latex`. IMHO well-designed LaTeX tables look very good. Usually the trick is to reduce the number of lines (horisontal lines are often unnecessary), but this is a matter of taste.